# iBook G4 12-inch hangs at grey Apple logo screen

Tags: performance

Today, I tried to use my Tiger install DVD to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.4.11 since Software Update kept crashing when I tried to upgrade to 10.4.11 that way. After upgrading with the DVD, it rebooted with a grey Apple logo, but the spinning wheel didn't appear afterwards.  I ran both the quick and extended hardware tests on the AHT CD that came with the iBook. NO ISSUES. I put the iBook in target disk mode via Open Firmware and booted from it on my PowerBook G4 Titanium, but the same thing happened. Are my computers' hard disks failing or what?

Comment: There are 4 models of iBook G4. According to MacTracker, only the 1st Gen iBook G4 (2003) could be upgraded to 10.4.11, while the succeeding three models could be upgraded to 10.5.8. Machines of this vintage most likely have non-functional hard drives. Have you been using the iBooks, or have they been sitting on a shelf somewhere?

Comment: @IconDaemon I am using my iBook G4 1st generation (2003).